# How to format a datetime so that Excel will understand it?

Tags: excel, datetime, csv

I have a script which outputs a CSV file. How should I format dates or date+time fields so that Excel will correctly parse that field as a date?

PS: I'd like to keep timezone information intact as well.

Comment: CSV is not a very well defined format, and, in international environments, their interpretation depends on the regional settings of the pc (dmy vs mdy).Even the comma can be replaced by a semicolon. I avoid that "non format" whenever possible.

Comment: I've never seen "the comma replaced by a semicolon" in a file claiming to be CSV.  In fact, I can't remember the last time I saw a CSV file that didn't follow RFC 4180 (<http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180>).  The only question is how to represent rich objects like datetimes.

Answer (score 5):

Excel's date format does not contain any information about time zones. I would export the time zone as a separate column, perhaps as an offset from GMT, like 5 or -2. I personally prefer the unambiguous yyyy-mm-dd date format.

Comment: +5 or -2 to Greenwich Mean Time (GMT), so for example, Eastern Standard Time would be -5 to GMT, whereas Paris would be +1.

Comment: well that's what I mean, how would anyone know?

Comment: Since in your question you say you would like to keep timezone information intact, I assume this information exists in your source data. In what format is your timezone data?

Answer (score -4):

I would use the "dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss" format. I have never had any problems with Excel understanding this format before.

Comment: Timezone would have to be added as a separate column.

Comment: Is this the same as the "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" format? Excel doesn't read this format correctly from CSV files. It reads the dates only in American format (mm/dd/yyyy), regardless of your regional settings. It's a bug in Excel as far as I can see.

Comment: @SDK That is not correct. At least for the Mac version ... I just tried importing the following csv file "11/01/2013 13:00:00"; 10 and excel parsed it as 11th of January ...

Comment: Every time you choose a bad date format, Jesus harpoons a baby whale.

Comment: Excel read the date from CSV using your computer locale. It means if your computer locale is American, that it  reads American. This makes CSV often incompatible producing different results on different computers.